# how to connect to remote coherence cache

Tags: java, caching, oracle-coherence

We are using coherence cache. but during Junit testing as the cache gets setup locally and takes a lot of time to load(as it is a fresh cache every time I run from Junit) hence delaying the unit testing upto 1.5 hrs. We also have test environments which use caches deployed on server boxes and as most of the data is loaded on these cache boxes, gives a good performance. 
Is there any way/configurations so that my Junit test can refer to the cache on server. This will dramatically reduce my testing efforts.

Thanks in advace.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 options

1) As this relates to JUnit use mocking to replicate the behavior you want.

2) You can always create unit testing specific coherence configuration files which point to an existing coherence grid and use them in during unit testing.

Comment: Thanks Kumar. Can you please tell me what all configurations need to be done for option 2.